# Convert weight to kilograms units if units and weight values are in different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset, however, I do have two columns, one for weights and another for weight units, I do want to perform some calculations on weights column but first I want to convert all of them to be in kilograms, so could someone help on how I can check the units column and if I find its grams I convert weights column values to kilograms:

Here is how the dataset looks like

```
import pandas as pd 

# intialise data of lists. 
data = {'Weghts':[2.00, 3.50, 2050.00, 4019.00],'weight_units':['Kilograms', 'kilograms', 'Grams', 'Grams']} 

# Create DataFrame 
dfy = pd.DataFrame(data) 

# Print the output. 
print(dfy)
```

my end results is all values in weights column to be in kilograms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide all matched values by `1000`:

```
dfy.loc[dfy['weight_units'].eq('Grams'), 'Weghts'] /= 1000
print(dfy)
   Weghts weight_units
0   2.000    Kilograms
1   3.500    kilograms
2   2.050        Grams
3   4.019        Grams
```

Or solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
dfy['Weghts'] = np.where(dfy['weight_units'].eq('Grams'), dfy['Weghts'] / 1000, dfy['Weghts'])
```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use numpy where and reassign values to the Weghts column:

```
df.assign(Weghts = lambda x: np.where(x.weight_units=="Grams",x.Weghts * .001, 
                                      x.Weghts))
```